# Regular expression on key press which takes one decimal value and allowed three digit after decimal

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I want a regular expression on key press which takes one decimal value and allowed three digit after decimal in JavaScript/MVC.

Comment: no need for JS, use the input's _pattern_ attribute.

Comment: Please don't just turn up and say "I want a regex, give it to me". Show what you've tried. Why should anyone help you if you've put no effort in yourself?

Comment: no need of regular expression here just use 
    var n = yourdecimalnumber.toFixed(3) it will do the job what you want

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you clarify what you mean by MVC? Are you referring to a JavaScript MVC framework or a server-side thing like ASP.NET MVC? Also, please provide more information to answer your question -- see [ask] for details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your kerpress event handler you can use this regular expression `^[0-9]\d*(\.\d{1,3})`

Answer (score -1):

you could use the [pattern attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) of the input , added with HTML 5 
or 
[Jquery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)